# How to Fix this CSS and Center the Menu Horizontally?

Tags: css, list, html-lists, centering, navbar

I'm trying to remove the vertical line in the menu just to the right of the "Contact Us" link, then center the entire menu bar. Here's the code (a JSFiddle link is at the bottom). Thanks in advance for your assistance :)

HTML:

```
<body>

<div id="page_wrapper">
<div class="page_padding">

<div id="header">
<div class="inner_padding">

</div>
</div>

<div id="menu_container">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Registration</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">User Programs</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Calendar</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="spacer"></div>
</div>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
body{
     margin:15px 0 15px 0;
     padding:0;
     line-height: 1.7em;
     text-align: center;
     font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif;
     font-size: 75%;     
}


#page_wrapper {
     width: 890px;
     border:1px solid #8A837D;
     background-color: #FFFFFF;
     margin: 0 auto;
     padding:0;
     text-align: left;
}

#header {
     background: #999E8A url('../img/#.jpg') top right no-repeat;
     height: 135px;
     padding-top:25px;
     margin:0;
}


#content_wrapper {
     float: left;
     width: 100%;
}

.inner_padding {
     margin: 10px; /*Margins for inner DIV inside each column (to provide padding)*/
}

.page_padding {
     margin: 15px; /*Margins for inner DIV inside each column (to provide padding)*/
}


#menu_container {
     margin:0;
     padding: 0;
}

#menu_container ul {
     padding-left: 0;
     margin: 0;
     background-color: #CC6600;
     color: White;
     float: left;
     width: 100%;
     font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
     font-size: 1.2em;
     font-weight: bold;
}

#menu_container ul li { display: inline; line-height: 1em;}

#menu_container ul li a {
     padding: 1em 1em 1em 1em;
     background-color: #CC6600;
     color: White;
     text-decoration: none;
     float: left;
     border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}

#menu_container ul li a:hover {
     background-color: #FF9933;
     color: #fff;
}

 .spacer {clear:both;}
```

[>>>> See example of above on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/94PsT/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the CSS rules `display: table` on the `<ul>` and `display: table-cell` on the `<li>`.  This will cause the menu to fit perfectly into the horizontal space.  I removed the `display: inline` and added `display: block` to the `<a>` tags.

To remove the border, you can use the `:first-child` or `:last-child` CSS selector.  I'd recommend using the :first-child, and then putting the border on the left of the `<a>`.  This is just because :first-child is supported in more browsers.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/94PsT/2/

Comment: I appreciate all the helpful responses. I found yours to be the most elegant & applicable solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[see this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/94PsT/3/)

css styles added

```
#menu_container {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    padding: 0 20px;
    background: #CC6600;
}

#menu_container ul li:last-child a{
    border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
edit css like this
```

demo:http://jsfiddle.net/94PsT/4/

```
  #menu_container ul {
padding-left: 0;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: #CC6600;
color: White;
width:92%;
font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 1.2em;
font-weight: bold;
 }

#menu_container ul li:last-child a {
padding: 1em 1em 1em 1em;
background-color: #CC6600;
color: White;
text-decoration: none;
float: left;
border-right: none;
 }
```